# Get token from URL in Django. TDAmeritrade API Call

Tags: django, django-urls

Ok,

I'm developing a website where I'm using Django. The website is for creating and keep track of stock portfolios. I have the database and the basics of the website set up but I would like to use the TDAmeritrade API in order to get the stock information. How it works is the user is redirected to TD where they enter there Login and Password they accept the terms and get transferred to a redirect page of the local host (until it goes live). Which looks a little like this

"https://127.0.0.1:8000/?code=" with a huge code after the equals sign.

Finally, how would one create the URL destination in Django url.py file and store the code for AUTH Token

I've tried something like this: **path('?code=', test_view, name='test'),**

but had no luck but that could be because of this error (You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.)

Thanks in advance!

Side note: I've tried looking up how Paypal does there send back confirmation but all I could find were packages Pre-build for Django

Comment: So you want to get `code` in `?code` ?

Comment: you can use api framework that django rest framework is for you.

Comment: @Moha369 No the url looks like this "https://127.0.0.1:8000/?code=OmiPO1VxMkdUnHTKxENgHE2kMvIuU3sKTXwEurSMtJP6PXo8CLgT%2BcwDFJESHnhRZEC8JfAtS%2BHqVwUFvuaUHyMA9nCY3zBZNt1a4LLUYoiYyGHvTR7k%2BLMfWu4kMXAYMnXZaxSLqvHYw%2F6MetOGZlIDTzgzW0fcTOg0d144qfeX4XL2IAIsaaCtjzvwihyQTLrKZbh1nlVM8wCyn0%2BNbewgGqEZaQSCVqz2pHQgg7Nwae99nmG5EAYFyHymuD36ktcgJHKrKq6zpTwg0sQ7Ir....Ect" and I need after the equals sign

Comment: @AliYaman i'm confused what your implying.... I understand how the urls work in django but not really sure how to format it.

Comment: Use `request.GET.get('code')`

Comment: @Moha369 Thank you!! That worked just needed to put it into the right place. I made a new view and tried grabbing it from there but i looked at the Django Docs on it and it is one slash before with the '?' which can be found here [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/]

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution with the help of Moha369 in the comments, So shout out to him/her!

```
def home_view(request):
context= {}
user = request.user
if user.is_authenticated:
    token = request.GET.get('code')
    print(token)
return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

[Django Docs that helped](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#what-the-urlconf-searches-against)